# call class method but only generator being returned

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to debug a method in a class. So in the iterative console I have imported my class using the line below.

> from email_reader import MyClass

I then thought I just had to set an instance of my class like below.

> ma_cls = MyClass('MyFolder')

Then I could call the function get_email like below,

> ma_cls.get_email(filename, date_from, date_to)

When I run it the breakpoints never get hit and all that is returned is below.

> Out[353]:

What am I doing wrong?

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self,
             outlook_folder: str):
    self.__outlook_folder = outlook_folder

  def get_email(self,
                           csv_filename: str,
                           emails_since: dt.datetime,
                           emails_to: dt.datetime = None,
                           unread_only: bool = False
                           ):

    breakpoint()

    # some logic



 if __name__ == "__main__":

 breakpoint()

 sse = MyClass("MyFolder")

for wt in sse.get_email(
        'some_file_name.CSV',
        emails_since=dt.datetime(2020, 2, 4),
        emails_to=dt.datetime(2020, 2, 5),
        unread_only=False):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Code block in

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

is executed only when the script is run directly (when you directly execute the script that contains your `MyClass`). If you are importing the above file then everything that is inside the above `if-statement` is simply ignored.